# Files created in terminal are hidden in Dropbox

Tags: terminal, dropbox

When I create text files in the terminal

```
echo "TEXT" > ~/Dropbox/test.txt
```

These files are hidden when Dropbox is accessed from another device. File permissions are set to 777.

Comment: when u do vi ~/Dropbox/test.txt does the file open?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering the path you entered is correct, it should show. 
try running 
`chflags nohidden ~/Dropbox/test.txt` 
and see if it unhides it for you

if its not showing the file, my guess is that the path you entered is incorrect. go to Dropbox folder and do pwd and see the path and use it